# Magento: Change Theme via Controller

Tags: model-view-controller, magento, themes

As the title says, is there a way to load a Magento theme from the Controller without switching store? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call `Mage::getDesign()->setTheme();`. The `getDesign` function returns an instance of `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package` if you need a reference for the expected arguments of `setTheme`.